# Scala Subclass change return type without override

Tags: scala

Let's say I have a class called `A`:

```
class A(i: Int) {
  //private def to initialize a calculated value
  def maintainedValue : Int = calculatedValue

  def double : A = new A(maintainedValue * 2)
  def combine(other: A) : A = new A(maintainedValue + other.maintainedValue)
  def addAmt(amt : Int) : A = new A(maintainedValue  + amt)
  // Many many more methods
}
```

I want to define a class `B` that extends class `A` such that it's methods, almost all of which have similar logic, return an object of class `B`:

```
class B(i: Int) extends A(i) {
  //private def to initialize a differently calculated value
  def maintainedValue : Int = diffCalculatedValue

  //Change all other methods to return type B without override???
}
```

Is it possible to do this without overriding all the methods?

Is there a simple way to instantiate these new instances with a variable/dynamic class?

Perhaps there is a more elegant way to do this?

Comment: This is a common-enough problem to be named: F-bounded polymorphism. Here's the simplest write-up I've seen: `http://www.alessandrolacava.com/blog/scala-self-recursive-types/`. talex's answer gets you most of the way there, but still has a few of the safety issues mentioned (and easily solved) in that post.

Answer (score 0):

How about having base trait with common logic and two implementation?

```
object App extends App {
  println(A(1).double)
  println(B(1).double)
}


trait A {
  type TYPE

  def create(i: Int): TYPE

  def maintainedValue: Int

  def double: TYPE = create(maintainedValue * 2)

  def addAmt(amt: Int): TYPE = create(maintainedValue + amt)
}

trait B extends A {
}

object A {

  def apply(i: Int) = new AImpl(i)

  case class AImpl(i: Int) extends A {
    override type TYPE = A

    override def create(i: Int) = A(i)

    override def maintainedValue: Int = 2
  }

}

object B {

  def apply(i: Int): B = new BImpl(i)

  case class BImpl(i: Int) extends B {

    override type TYPE = B

    override def create(i: Int): TYPE = B(i)

    override def maintainedValue: Int = 1
  }

}
```

Comment: The classes should be subclasses of one-another. The code I posted was a simple example, but the contents of the classes are a bit more complicated and while the fields are the same, how they are handled in certain methods are not. That being said, if I try to reference another method in the trait, I still get a type mismatch. I will edit my question to better show what I mean

Comment: I updated my example according new requirement. Made `A` and `B` traits and hide implementation.

Comment: I added a method called yesterday `combine(other: A)`, which if added to the trait will cause a type mismatch (at least when I tried it).

Comment: That's happened because type is co or countrvariant. Imagine to have instance of class B, assign it to var with type A and try to call combine(a). You should think about removing inheritance and make you type generic.

Answer (score 0):

One solution, and the simplest one in my opinion, is to change class `A` to have a structure such that a single method handles object creation:

```
def create(i: Int): TYPE = new B(i)
```

And just use an implicit method in class `B` to handle casting when calling the unaltered methods:

```
private implicit def convert(a: A): B = new B(a.maintainedValue)
```

Short and sweet, though I'm curious how efficient and/or scale-able this solution is.